# Writing a large 2d array to Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I'm looking to write a large 2d array to an Excel worksheet using C#.  If the array is 500 x 500, the code that I would use to write this is as follows:

```
 var startCell = Worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
 var endCell = Worksheet.Cells[500, 500];
 var writeRange = (Excel.Range)Worksheet.Cells[startCell, endCell;
 writeRange.Value = myArray;
```

I get an exception on this line:

```
var endCell = Worksheet.Cells[500, 500];
```

As anybody who has used C# and Excel via COM can testify, the error message received is pretty much useless.  I think that the issue is that the underlying data structure used for the worksheet is not of sufficient size to index cell 500,500 when I first create the sheet.

Does anybody know how to achieve the desired result?  I'm hoping that there is a simple way to re-size the underlying data structure before creating the Range.

Thanks.

Edit:  Error message is:

```
{"Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"}
```

With and excel error code of -2146827284.

Update:  The link supplied in the comments below alluded to an issue with opening the Excel sheet in compatibility mode.  This does seem to be the problem.  If I save the document in .xlsx or .xlsm format before running my code, this seems to work.  My issue is that I cannot expect my users to do this each time.  Is there a programmitcal way of achieving this?  Would it simply be a case of opening the file, checking the extension and then saving it in the new format if needed?

Comment: Although it is "pretty much useless", it would be interesting that you tell us what you see. Maybe you have this problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range)?

Comment: be aware that in older versions of excel (e.g. 2003), your sheets can't have more than 256 columns (the last one is IV) and 65536 rows, so they can't contain a 500*500 matrix without splitting it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution.

Instead of using Worksheet.Cells[x, x], use Worksheet.get_range(x, x) instead.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a small example that worked for me. Originally found at [**SO this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536636/write-array-to-excel-range). I had to adapt this answer as in my Interop assembly (*Excel 14 Object Library*) there is **no more method** `Worksheet.get_Range(.., ..)`

```
var startCell = ws.Cells[1, 1];
int row = 500, col = 500;
var endCell = ws.Cells[row, col];
try
{
    // access range by Property and cells indicating start and end           
    var writeRange = ws.Range[startCell, endCell];
    writeRange.Value = myArray;
}
catch (COMException ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same as my code above, and this does work in normal circumstances.  The issue is when the workbook opens in Compatibility Mode.

Comment: I am currently working on a new example. Pls confirm some assumptions: the programm shall open a file, according to the current version of file (<excel 2010 or not) programm should split values on multiple sheets or if xlVersion is 2010 give all values on one sheet?