# 502 response when uploading large files to asp4 site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, http-error

Our site is able to handle files up to what seems 100mb.

- When I upload a 100mb file, I receive the 502 bad gateway error after about 2 minutes and 20 seconds
- When I upload a 200mb file, I receive the 502 bad gateway error after about 4 minutes
- The above are only happening when `<compilation debug="false".../>`
- **When I set the `<compilation debug="true".../>` it succeeds**

In my web.config I've got settings for both `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` set to over a gig. I've also tried the `executionTimeout` setting, and it seems to have no effect.

I'm curious though in both the ~2 minute and ~4 minute requests that result in an error response... I can see that the server is actually doing the work with the file being uploaded. It's taking it, and putting it on a file share successfully and it's also going through and entering a row in our DB to track it... but it responds with a 502.

Running locally or running with `<compilation debug="true".../>` succeeds, if that helps at all.

Comment: Similar to [ASP.Net request raises 502 Bad Gateway or TimeOut](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18021607/4519059).