# Fast Export to Excel using transpose

Tags: excel, vb.net, export-to-excel

i used a solution posted in this link
[Fast Export of Large Datatable to Excel Spreadsheet in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388592/fast-export-of-large-datatable-to-excel-spreadsheet-in-vb-net)

and worked very well, however when my code export more than 15513 lines the code fail and only appears "#N/A" on columns. like shown on image below

[Error on export a big number of lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxBXt.png)
see the code used:

```
        'numero de linhas
        Dim Nbligne As Long = dt.Rows.Count

        'Grava o cabeçalho das colunas e os dados
        For Each dc In dt.Columns

            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            'Cabeçalhos
            oWsh.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
            oWsh.Cells(2, colIndex).Resize(Nbligne, ).Value = oXls.Application.transpose(dt.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)().[Select](Function(k) CObj(k(dc.ColumnName))).ToArray())

        Next
```

PS: this code continue to running in current application, because only in few cases i have more than 15000 records, but  i need a definitive solution for this problem. ;-)

can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receive a large number of records in this routine, i could verify that this error ocurred in a specific situation that not happened again. I believe this error could be caused by a caracter in a varchar field.

thus it is not necessary a correction on routine.

So, thanks for reading my question ;-)