# Export more than 100,000 rows from wpf datagrid to Excel - C# Microsoft.Office Interop 14

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid, ms-office

I have the following problem: in my WPF-application I do provide data in a datagrid and the user can export the grid`s data to Excel via an object array as it is described in this [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536636/write-array-to-excel-range).
Well, it works fine as long as there are less than 100,000 rows to export. But I cannot export more than 100,000 rows. Then Excel won`t open, but I can see in task manager that an Excel process has been startet but is doing nothing and has around 5 MB assigned to it. However, my program ist not blocked and doesn`t report any exception.
And it doesn`t matter how many columns there are - the limit seems to be 100,000 rows.

Further details that may be relevant:
Tested environment:
- Win 7/XP/8 (32 Bit)
- Office 2010 
- Microsoft.Office.Interop 14
- .NET 4.0 Client Profile

Althoug I`m offering the user a lot of filter options so he/she can easily export packets to excel files and put them together to one big file - but it should be possible to let it be done by the software as the Excel limit in 2010 is about 1,000,000 rows.

Comment: In case of really big data sets that should be stored in *Excel* you should consider using `csv` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the end I couldn`t find out why 100,000 rows was the limit for export via Interop. I ended up using Open XML SDK with the help of the [Open XML Powertools](http://powertools.codeplex.com/) in a streaming approach as [documented by Eric White](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2012/01/10/screen-cast-using-open-xml-and-linq-to-xml-in-a-streaming-fashion-to-create-huge-spreadsheets.aspx). Work`s perfectly for any size (performance is 1,000 rows/second) and you don`t need the Interop. Just start the created XLSX-file by using the following line:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(completeFilename);
```