# Fastest way to generate Excel from datagridview with formatting

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview, export-to-excel

I have a code to **export data** from `datagridview` to Excel sheet but the problem is it is very slow because it is **inserting data and formatting each cell**.

How can I improve performance of this operation?

Below is my code

```
public static void ExcelExport(DataGridView Dg, string TypePass)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
    ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    Excel_12.ApplicationClass oExcel_12 = null;           //Excel_12 Application
    Excel_12.Workbook oBook = null;                       // Excel_12 Workbook
    Excel_12.Sheets oSheetsColl = null;                   // Excel_12 Worksheets collection
    Excel_12.Worksheet oSheet = null;                     // Excel_12 Worksheet
    Excel_12.Range oRange = null;                         // Cell or Range in worksheet
    Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    oExcel_12 = new Excel_12.ApplicationClass();
    oExcel_12.UserControl = true;
    oBook = oExcel_12.Workbooks.Add(oMissing);
    oSheetsColl = oExcel_12.Worksheets;
    oSheet = (Excel_12.Worksheet)oSheetsColl.get_Item("Sheet1");

    oRange = (Excel_12.Range)oSheet.Cells[1, 1];
    oRange.Value2 = "";
    oRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
    oRange.Font.Size = 12;
    (oRange).Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
    (oRange).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Gray);

    if (TypePass.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        oRange = (Excel_12.Range)oSheet.Cells[2, 1];
        oRange.Value2 = TypePass;
        oRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
        oRange.Font.Size = 10;
    }

    int c = 0;

    if (Dg.ColumnHeadersVisible == true)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Dg.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            if (Dg.Columns[j].Visible == true)
            {
                oRange = (Excel_12.Range)oSheet.Cells[4, c + 1];
                oRange.Value2 = Dg.Columns[j].HeaderText + "  ";
                oRange.Font.Bold = true;
                oRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
                oRange.Font.Size = 9;
                (oRange).Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                (oRange).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Teal);
                oExcel_12.Columns.AutoFit();
                c++;
            }
        }
    }

    c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Dg.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < Dg.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            if (Dg.Columns[j].Visible == true)
            {
                oRange = (Excel_12.Range)oSheet.Cells[i + 5, c + 1];
                if (Dg[j, i].Value == null)
                {
                    oRange.Value2 = " ";
                }
                else
                {
                    oRange.Value2 = Dg[j, i].Value.ToString().Replace('\n', ' ') + "  ";
                }

                oRange.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
                oRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
                oRange.Font.Size = 8;
                oExcel_12.Columns.AutoFit();
                // oRange.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                c++;
            }
        }
        c = 0;
    }

    oExcel_12.Visible = true;
    oBook = null;
    oExcel_12 = null;
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: You could use `OleDb` but no formatting get's carried out and OleDb treats your Excel as a database.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx) if you like.

I have used Open XML for export data to Excel spreadsheet (.XLSX format) and i can assure that performances are great.

- I can generate 50,000 cell spreadsheet within 2, 3 seconds
- 1 Million    cell spreadsheet within 60 seconds [That's 10,000 Row
  100 Column    spreadsheet]

What you need to know :

- Lean how spreadsheet is  structured
- Follow given guides [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278328(v=office.15).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/cc861607(v=office.15).aspx)
- Learn about Styling [kind of PRO level which enables many possibilities]
- Work with [Open XML Productivity tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) ; Will ease your learning curve [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSSMLR19JWA)

Advantage :

- you can create well formatted Excel sheets without having Office
  package installed.
- Also you can expand spreadsheet generating even to    server side if
  you like.
- At first you will feel it's hard compared to InterOp , but once you have properly implemented you will be able to use same Excel spreadsheet function for **ANY** project.!

Comment: I second him regarding OpenXml. Using it myself!

Comment: Open XML file formats started from 2007 . So yes for 2007 upwords. 

For 2003 and XP versions you have Service packs which enable you to work with .XLSX files Link - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924074

Comment: sorry for the late response but the problem is still unsolved

Answer (score 3):

If you decide to stick in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, you can utilize the code by setting the format and data in range properly.

1. Set header styles for 1 row
2. Set content styles from columns * row
3. Build array from the DataGridView cell values then write it in range is a very quick way: [Write Array to Excel Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536636/write-array-to-excel-range)

Btw, GC.Collect cannot serve the purpose for close the COM object, please reference to [Proper disposal of COM interop objects in C# particularly MS Office applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1893653/1287352)

Comment: "GC.Collect" here is only used to remove the memory it was using to create excel "Book" and i kind of like your idea so i upvoted your answer but i need a way which takes minimal time in generating tge report.

Answer (score 1):

MS Office Interop is slow and even Microsoft does not recommend Interop usage on server side. For more details see what Microsoft stated on [why not to use OLE Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

Microsoft Excel released XLSX file format with Office 2007 and recommends the usage of OpenXML SDK instead of Interop.

If you must save Excel files in XLS file format, you can use an Excel library like [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com).

See the following code sample as alternative of exporting DataGridView to Excel:

```
// Create a DataSet and add the DataTable of DataGridView 
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.Tables.Add((DataTable)dataGridView);//or ((DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource).Copy() to create a copy

// Export Excel file 
ExcelDocument workbook = new ExcelDocument();
workbook.easy_WriteXLSFile_FromDataSet(filePath, dataSet, 
       new EasyXLS.ExcelAutoFormat(EasyXLS.Constants.Styles.AUTOFORMAT_EASYXLS1), 
       "Sheet1");
```

For exporting the formatting that you need you can create your own ExcelAutoFormat. Check this code sample on [how to export datagridview to Excel in C# with formatting](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/export-datagridview-to-excel.html).

Comment: yes, it does. The xls file format is for Office 2003. The code sample is for Offce 2003.