# What is the fastest way to get data from vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, export

I have a loop which run about 300,000 times at every iteration I stored:

```
time_elps = stwt.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
read.Add(time_elps, OFV_best)
```

Finally I just want to take the values of `read` (a dictionary of course) to draw a graph on excel.

I tried to export this data to excel:

```
oxl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
oxl.Visible = True
owb = oxl.Workbooks.Add
osheet = owb.ActiveSheet

For i = 0 To 100
    osheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = read.Item(read.Keys.ElementAt(i))
    osheet.Cells(i + 1, 2).value = read.Keys.ElementAt(i)
Next
```

and to a text file:

```
objStreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\Dr. Mohamed ElWakil\Desktop\data.txt")

For i = 0 To read.Count - 1
    objStreamWriter.WriteLine(CStr(read.Item(read.Keys.ElementAt(i)) & "," & (read.Keys.ElementAt(i))))
Next

objStreamWriter.Close()
```

In two cases it takes too too much time, it's longer than the time of running the code itself.

What do you suggest to get my data easily and fast?

Comment: Which for loop takes too much time? In the case of the first one, you're only doing 100 iterations whereas the second would do the full 300,000.

Comment: The value retrieval might be the operation that takes most of the time. Try iterating with `foreach var pair in read`. You will get a pair with key and value and do not need to query the value by key.

Comment: @SEFL, extracting data either by excel or by text file takes too much time .. the algorithm or the code may be finish operating in two minutes but I keep waiting about 15 mins to get all the data

Comment: @NicoSchertler, I will try it, I hope it work, thank you

Comment: I suggest you should use 2D array to write in excel, it much faster (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536636/write-array-to-excel-range).  Moreover, you should turn the ***auto calculate*** off before you write in excel

Comment: @NicoSchertler, your way with the txt file is the fastest one, thank you sir ..

Comment: Then also check if you really need a dictionary or if a simple list of pairs is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every time I creat a new txt file with name "data" tailed with time.hour and time.minute

as @NicoSchertler, using for each var in read to get var.value and var.key

this is the fastest way

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
Dim path As String
path = "C:\Users\Dr. Mohamed ElWakil\Desktop\data" & Now.Hour & Now.Minute & ".txt"
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(path, True)

For Each var In read
    file.WriteLine(var.Key & "," & var.Value)
Next

file.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing each value seperately to Excel is just really slow, have a go with this:

```
   Dim arr2D(100, 1) As String
    For i = 0 To 100
        arr2D(i, 0) = read.Item(read.Keys.ElementAt(i))
        arr2D(i, 1) = read.Keys.ElementAt(i)
    Next
    Dim oExcel As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim oWorkbook As Object = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
    Dim oWorksheet As Object = oWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim vRange As Object = oWorksheet.Range("A1")
    vRange = vRange.Resize(UBound(arr2D, 1) + 1, UBound(arr2D, 2) + 1)
    vRange.Formula = arr2D
    vRange.Columns.autofit()
    oExcel.Visible = True
```

Comment: I think this is the best way for excel, I have tried it 
but write to a txt file is faster than this and copying from a dictionary to a two dimension array consumes time too 
and I tried 'read' to be a two dimensional array from the beginning but I have to 'redim' it every time and that takes a time too