# vb.net writing Array of Arrays to excel Range worksheet

Tags: excel, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I have a windows form that asks user for some inputs. Creates a 2 d array. Then opens a new excel workbook and writes the array to cells in that workbook.
Everything seem to be working as I would expect, except for the values being placed in the cells is "System.Int64[][]" instead of the values from the array.

Below is the code starting where i create my 2d array (a function call). Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
'Get Final Array
    Dim fArray As Long()()
    fArray = getFArray(numVars, numCombos, stepNumsArray, jArray)
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim xlApp As New excel.Application
    Try
        Dim xlBook As excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        Dim xlWS1 As excel.Worksheet = CType(xlBook.Worksheets(1), excel.Worksheet)
        xlApp.Visible = True
        Dim R As excel.Range
        R = xlWS1.Cells.Range("A2:C13")
        R.Value = fArray.ToString

        xlWS1.SaveAs(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\" & "Test.xlsx")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Export to Excel Error: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        xlApp.Workbooks.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
        xlApp = Nothing

    End Try
```

Comment: The default implementation of `Object.ToString()` is to output the `Type.FullName` of the object.

Comment: I have no clue about the Excel API, but you could try assigning the array directly to the value: `R.Value = fArray`.  Failing that you may need to loop over the cells in your range and set the individually.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536636/write-array-to-excel-range

Answer (score 0):

The main issues are the use of jagged array instead of rectangular array, using `.ToString` on array, and using `Long` instead of `Double` (Excel uses `Double` for all numeric types). Once those are fixed:

```
Dim fArray(11, 2) As Double
' ...
xlWS1.Range("A2:C13").Value2 = fArray
```